# Associate a pvalue to set intersection

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a set $S$ of $N$ elements; then I do three independent samplings from $S$, and I create three sets $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ of sizes $N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_3$. Let $N_{int}$ be the size of the intersection of the three, i.e., the cardinality of the set of elements of $S$ that are also in $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$.

I would like to associate to $N_{int}$ a p-value, for example computing the probability of having a greater intersection if the three subset were choosen randomly.

If I had only two of such sets (say $R_1$ and $R_2$) I would have used the `hypergeometric` distribution; how can I extend to this case?

I have been trying by bootstrapping, but since my observation is very significant it would require to many iterations to beat it.

Comment: As you mentioned, the number of elements of $R_1 \cap R_2$, $|R_1\cap R_2|$ has a hypergeometric distribution. Conditional on $|R_1\cap R_2| = r$, the number of elements of $R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3$ also has a hypergeometric distribution. So you compute the weighted sum to obtain the pmf - and it could be ugly.

Comment: Many thanks @BGM . I cannot understand how to compute the "weighted sum", could you provide some hints please?

Comment: I mean the law of total probability - let $Y = |R_1 \cap R_2|$ and $Z = |R_1 \cap R_2 \cap R_3|$. Then the pmf $\Pr\{Z = z\} = \sum_r \Pr\{Z = z|Y = r\}\Pr\{Y = r\}$.
You know the summand as it is the product of two hypergeometric pmfs. I am not sure if this sum has a nice closed-form.